Can plants metabolize iron rust?
It is widely accepted that "throwing rusty nails in the garden doesn't provide nutrients to the plants"(my very similar question on gardening.SE). I was under the impression this is due to iron being in third oxidation state there while biological processes generally use Fe(II). However plants seem to be used to Fe(III)! Perhaps it has something to do with breaking up the oxides?
What is the reason from chemistry point of view for most plants not to be able to break down

hydrous iron(III) oxides (Fe2O3·nH2O) and iron(III) oxide-hydroxide (FeO(OH), Fe(OH)3) (src: wiki)

? Does really none of the paragraph of acids in @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx's answer in the linked question "work"? Assume pH, moisture etc are fine. The soil is iron depleted soil mixed with powdered iron rust.
Let us also assume no steps have been taken to achieve "good" rust.

With limited dissolved oxygen, iron(II)-containing materials are favoured, including FeO and black lodestone or magnetite (Fe3O4).
source


Strategies I and II for dealing with Fe(III) are detailed in the linked paper. Do you have reason to doubt the paper's content? Which part stumped you? Depends a lot on soil pH and other conditions. Can you tell us more what you're after?

Just looked it up, there are over 400,000 different species of land-based plant - you'd get a clearer answer if you've a specific one in mind.

I have changed the word “digest” to “metabolize”, as that is the correct scientific usage. (The uptake and transport stages might not be termed “metabolism “, but they would certainly not be termed “digestion”.)

See this similar question on Gardening & Landscaping SE: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/59059/40386

Keep in mind that unless someone has done a controlled experiment supplementing soil with rusty nails and measuring plant growth, any claims about whether or not rusty nails help will rely on some assumptions about soil chemistry and plant physiology that may or may not actually hold in the field. Therefore, a definitive answer might be hard to find.

You appear to have remove the link that answered your question, and now refer and are now asking us to comment on an answer to a question on another list. Whether or not the effect of throwing rusty nails in gardens is widely accepted or not, it is not the concern of a site for biological science professionals and students. It would appear that you have little familiarity with chemistry from your general use of inappropriate terms — originally "digestion", rather than "metabolism", now "break down". I suggest you go back to the expert review, rather than persisting here.
